# Existence of a right inverse to a surjective linear map without picking a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f\colon V\to W$ be a surjective linear map between $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. Then $f$ admits a right inverse/ section $s$ such that $f\circ s = id_W$.

Is there a way to prove the existence of a right inverse without picking a basis?

Comment: Yes you can, but still assuming AC (see [this](/questions/2431584) for example).